# How can I find if user input is inclusive in list of arbitrary integers in Python 3.3.0

Tags: python, list, if-statement

Here is some code for a function I am writing that outputs whether a given date is valid or not:

```
date = (input("Please enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy): "))
monthStr, dayStr, yearStr = date.split("/")
monthStr = int(monthStr)
dayStr = int(dayStr)
yearStr = int(yearStr)
Mylist1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]
```

So I'd like to make an if and statement that would look like this but I don't know the syntax or method:

```
if monthStr (is == one of the integers in)Mylist and dayStr (is in) range(0,32):
print("Valid date")
else:
print("Not a Valid date")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty intuitive

```
if monthStr in Mylist1 and dayStr in range(0, 32):
    print("Valid date")
else:
    print("Not a Valid date")
```

However your variable names are not very good, you should pick more relevant names since `monthStr` is not actually a string.

Comment: Thank you very much, and I did change the variable names. That's exactly the answer I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `in` keyword:

```
if month in months and day in range(1, 32):
```

I'd also rename your variables. `dayStr` is an integer, not a string.